# How to hide specified cells if specific cell is value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to hide rows 10-16 if the value in B9 is "No". If Yes, then they would remain unhidden, so if it changes from No to Yes, it would unhide.

I know that I will need to do an onEdit along with sheet.hideRow(range), but I can't figure out the If function with it

Comment: Pleade [edit] to show the code  that you've tried, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Your Sheet Name" || e.range.rowStart != 9 || e.range.columnStart != 2 ) return;
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.value == "Yes")sh.hideRows(10,6);
  if(e.value == "No")sh.showRows(10,6);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)